# Large coroutine vs many small coroutines?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Kotlin, we can use coroutines to offload network API from the main thread. I wonder which is better:

```
val r1=launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   api1()
}
val r2=launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   api2(r1)
}
val r3=launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   api3(r2)
}
```

or

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO){
val r1=api1()
val r2=api2(r1)
val r3=api3(r2)
}
```

Comment: These aren’t comparable. In the first you are passing Job objects to the second and third api function calls. In the second example you are passing whatever the api calls return to the second and third api function calls.

Comment: Extending thoughts of @Tenfour04, First will include parallelism, second will wait for one to complete then start second. It depends on what you need (You can however make first one do one by one, by joining other jobs). For blocking calls, which usually takes long to complete (and do not depend on each other) I'd prefer first way, otherwise (if they depend on one another) I'd go with second (and to make them cancellable, I'll check for `CoroutineScope.isActive` in between two blocking process).

Comment: Seeing `Dispatchers.IO` is also suspicious: you aren't really leveraging coroutines if all you use them for is submitting jobs to an old-school Java Executor, doing classic blocking IO. The "lightweight" aspect of coroutines is gone in your code.